# How to control a HTML5 website through Kinect v2?

Tags: javascript, windows, kinect, zigfu

I'm trying to build a HTML5 website that can be controlled through Kinect v2, meaning navigation through pages, pushing buttons, playing videos, etc. I was able to start this project with Kinect v1 using Zigfu but the requirements of the project changed and now I have to use the Kinect v2. Zigfu is not compatible with Kinect v2.
Do you have any other suggestions, what should I use in order to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Hi man, we both are on the same boats, I am also trying to control Google Earth using Kinect. What have you achieved so far? Can you guide me how do I start?

Comment: Hi @Faizan, I'm sorry I cannot help you with this since I didn't find any answer to it yet and so we postponed the project for a while. Good luck.

Comment: I see... Do you know of any person who would be a good person to talk to regarding what I want to acheive?

Comment: Hi, I'm fairly interested as well if you get any clue on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible, as the only way you can use the JavaScript API for kinect v2 is in a winJS store app. You could try to embed a web browser on the app. Check this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c285b9ae-a8d3-4ed7-bcf6-0b05b03deebf/developing-with-javascript-vs-wpf-c?forum=kinectv2sdk

Answer (score 1):

You may use HTML5 Web Socket to make data communication between kinect and your website. When you can access kinect data from your browser, you can easily design your desired control logic with the data. I've used [this](https://github.com/peted70/kinectv2-webserver) web socket server to develop a project. You may check this. There's a Test site inside it, which shows real time color data and body data in a web page from kinect.